# Error al ejecutar "composer update" en post-update-cmd

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, composer

Al lanzar un composer Update dentro de un proyecto me muestra el siguiente error:

> Generating autoload files
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   php artisan optimize
>   Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

El proyecto es este: https://github.com/KodeBlog/Laradmin.git

En el archivo `composer.json` tengo estos `scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
```

La versión de `Composer` es la **1.4.1**

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Según se comenta [**aquí**](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5623) (enlace en inglés) no es ningún error del composer, simplemente hubo una petición que falló,

Comment: Si, llegué a ese post, pero, resulta que falla el 100% de las veces, entonces, habrá alguna solución o algún otro modulo por el cual reemplazar el post-install-cmd, pero no lo he encontrado.

Answer (score 2):

El error tiene que ver con la version de PHP. Si tuvieras en ese servidor PHP 5.4 por ejemplo (o varias versiones pero por default 5.4) ese sería el problema.

Chequea: `php -v`

Eso te da la pauta de que version se ejecuta al correr `php artisan optimize`